# Couldn't find a part of path error

Tags: c#

Well,I have been trying to get geo-location of an IP Address using a site you can see in the code,but I keep getting a error (here i tried to get location of 46.228.199.20)

> Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Laza\moji programi\Projects\Jj2 list\bin\Debug\freegeoip.net\json\46.228.199.20'.

The code is :

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
byte[] locationbyte = wc.DownloadData("freegeoip.net/json/" + ip);
string location = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(locationbyte);
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try prefixing the URL with the scheme you want to use:

```
wc.DownloadData("http://freegeoip.net/json/" + ip);
```

If you carefully read the error, it seems to be interpreted as a relative local path when the scheme is omitted.